# what should in write in number of section count

Tags: swift

Here is my code

```
struct data {
    var name = [String]()
    var rollnumber = [Int]()
    var imge = [String]()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var arrname = [data]()
    let oject = data.init(name: ["Rohit","Mohit","Rahul","sam"], rollnumber: [32,23,83,76], imge:
                            ["grapres","lily","mango","marigold"])
```

Tableview's method

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return
}
```

Comment: How many sections do you want your table view to have?

Comment: I want 4 sections  but instead of number what can i write

Comment: Why don't you want to write a number?

Comment: Naming you `struct` `data` is not a good idea. It should be starting with an uppercase (`data` -> `Data`), but then would collide with `Foundation.Data` (default class in "Default" Framework). Now, `name` & `img` are both array, while they should be synced. (What if you don't have the same number of `imge` & `name`, and `rollNumber`? I guess you append `object` to `arrname`, if that's the case, then the number of section is `arrname[0].name.count` or ``arrname[0].rollnumber.count` or `arrname[0].imge.count`. And why is `arrname` an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit
    struct studentData {
        var name:[String]!
        var idNumber:[Int]!
        var image:[UIImage]!
    }
 
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    var arrDetails = [studentData]()
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       let data = studentData.init(name: ["anjali","shubham","deepak","amit","harsh","pari","ishu","aditya","taniya"], idNumber: [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009], image: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower3"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower2"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower4"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower5"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower3"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower2"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower4")])
        arrDetails.append(data)
    
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrDetails[0].name.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrDetails.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath)as! TableViewCell
        cell.lblOne.text = arrDetails[indexPath.row].name[indexPath.section]
        cell.lblTwo.text = "\(arrDetails[indexPath.row].idNumber[indexPath.section])"
        cell.imgPicture.image = arrDetails[indexPath.row].image[indexPath.section]
        return cell
    }
}
```